# branching in assembly without wasting storage space or knowing addresses - 8051

Tags: assembly, switch-statement, function-pointers, memory-address, 8051

I'm currently creating code for the 8051 processor and everytime I perform a typical branching routine (where the function that executes is determined on a variable value), a large amount of space is used for it. I'll explain with code and comments.

My typical code for branching follows this format:

```
nextround:
acall getuserinput
mov A,uservalue
cjne A,#option1,skipoption1 ;uses 3 bytes and 2 clock cycles for each cjne
    acall function1
    ajmp theend
skipoption1:
cjne A,#option2,skipoption2
    acall someotherfunction
    acall function2
    ajmp theend
skipoption2:
....
theend:
ajmp nextround
```

After finding out that the jmp command exists, I want to try to take advantage of it so I don't waste 3 extra bytes of storage and 2 extra clock cycles for each option.

Here's what I thought of so far:

```
nextround:
acall getuserinput
mov A,uservalue
anl A,#7h ;limit options to 8
mov DPTR,#processingspace
xch A,DPH ;set A=data pointer high and DPH=our value
add A,DPH ;add the two together
mov DPH,A ;so that we have 256 bytes available per option
clr A
jmp @A+DPTR
ajmp nextround

processingspace:    
;system jumps here if uservalue is 0
```

Now the part that is challenging is the last part of assigning addresses with words.

The easiest way out for me is to do something like this:

```
processingspace:    
;system jumps here if uservalue is 0
setb P1.1
nop ;add 253 nops

value1:    
;system jumps here if uservalue is 1
```

Its because then nops add the padding necessary to make the correct location of the code in memory.

Without using "org" directives, is there a more efficient way I can have the system jump to a program location for each function when it gets called based on a user choice and without wasting too much rom space?

Comment: Normally you use a table with the addresses for the jumps.

Comment: But if I use a pointer containing pointers then I'm still wasting 2 bytes per choice (for the second jump found in the table)

Comment: Yes, 1 or 2 bytes per choice. Nothing is for free.